# 400 (Bad Request) error in time of creating question using StackExchange API

Tags: support

I am trying to create a question in StackOverFlow using write-access API(https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/add). I have provided the parameters as required but a "400(Bad Request)" error is being returned on firing a POST request. While I have tried to create the question through the API Console,with same "key" and "access_token" it  works.I cannot understand what I am missing while creating the question through code.Following are the parameters that I have passed fro code:

```
API: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/add
Parameters:

                access_token: "TOKEN))" 
                body: "This is a test question body" 
                client_id: "3980" 
                key: "KEY((" 
                site: "stackoverflow" 
                tags: ".NET" 
                title: "This is a test title"
                preview: "true"
```

Could anybody please help me with a solution?

Comment: Could anybody please help me on this? I am stuck up in posting questions for hours. Tried every alternatives.Need a solution ASAP.

Comment: **Edit your question to provide an MCVE.** You did form-encode the parameters, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I think encoding is done. The url is as following: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/add?site=stackoverflow&access_token=TOKEN&body=This+is+a+test+body&client_id=3980&title=This+is+a+test+title&tags=C%23%2c.NET&preview=True&key=KEY  Are you talking about any special kind of encoding?

Comment: I got a better information on the 400 error. The error message from the server is: "POST methods expects all parameters to be submitted as a form, not on the query string". I am firing the POST request using C# code. Could anybody provide a C# or other langauge's code snippet to call a stackexchange API using POST?

Comment: I have added following content header from my C# code: client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); Please help me solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am just 2 years late to answer your question :-( but this should help for anyone else looking for a C# solution.

```
    private static async Task<Type> PostToStackOverflowAsync<Type>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> values) where Type : new()
    {
        string jsonText;
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    using (var zipstream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(zipstream))
                        {
                            jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(jsonText);
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            //  throw ex;
            return new Type();
        }
    }   



   var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {                    
                    {"preview", "false"},                    
                    {"access_token", accessToken},
                      {"site", "stackoverflow"},
                    {"key", key_}
                };   

   string url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/{0}/answers/{1}/upvote";
   PostToStackOverflowAsync<T>(string.Format(url, version_, id), dict);
```